# Is this an appropriate way to test a 7805?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, 7805

Trying to check some 7805 voltage regulators. I do not have a DC power supply and do not want to test with the circuit hooked up to mains. That leaves me and my multi-meter.

http://www.androiderode.com/how-to-test-voltage-regulator-ic/

This seems reasonable to me, and both of my 7805s have failed step 4. Before I go out and buy two new ones I was hoping that I could get some confirmation of this method.

Thank you

Comment: Have you got a 9V battery? If so, connect the battery + to VIN, the - to GND, and then measure the voltage between VOUT and GND.

Comment: @TomCarpenter oh wow yea I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Testing a 78xx 'hooked up to mains' would be rather interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is NOT a proper or useful way to test 3-terminal regulators.  The technique is valid for SOME (but not all) kinds of transistors. But it is completely unsuitable for an integrated circuit like a 3-terminal regulator. It will yield unpredictable (and most likely meaningless and misleading) results.

If you don't have a DC power supply, why do you even need to test 3-terminal regulators?  For that matter why do you even need 3-terminal regulators at all? Absent the context it is not clear what you are trying to do here?

You can use batteries as a DC source. Remember that you typically need 3V HIGHER input voltage than the regulator puts out.  It would also be prudent to put a LOAD on the output of the regulator. At least something around 500 to 1000 ohms or so.

Comment: The TI (National) data sheet says the minimum input voltage is 7.5V for LM7805  To be sure there are more modern products with lower dropout voltages, but the 79xx and 79xx are not "low dropout" products.

Comment: Hey Richard! You were helping me before on another forum. Still trying to fix my Turntable. This is where I am at if you are curious. Trying to determine if I have some blown voltage regulators and that is why nothing is coming on! http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246569/learning-by-doing-fixing-turntable

Comment: Right,I missed that part.So that translates into 0.5V unwanted dissipation?

Comment: @Coberra, Get a proper step-down transformer (not a toy plastic "travel converter") and work on the problem from the mains power input. If you don't have power coming in, then it is a moot point whether there may be additional problems downstream.

Comment: @Daniel Tork  No, the ENTIRE DIFFERENCE between the input voltage and the output voltage is "unwanted dissipation".  But older, analog designs needed a larger voltage differential to work with. More modern switching (and even linear) regulators are more efficient.

Comment: Ok,I understand.The datasheet confused me.I don't understand why they didn't list a max  voltage drop,instead placing 2V for the typical voltage drop and 7.5V at the min supply voltage

Comment: The MAXIMUM voltage drop is 30V.  The absolute maximum input voltage for the 78xx regulators is 35V. Which means that the 5V 7805 is the worst case if you have 35V going in and 5V coming out.

Comment: @RichardCrowley actually that one I showed on the other forums is a proper converter. Picked it up at an electronics shop here in Amsterdam. Plugged the unit into mains today and have power coming out of the secondary of the transformer in both yellow and blue wires. All diodes on the MOTOR PCB are working properly so that is why I am moving onto checking voltage regulators. My plan from here is to get a breadboard, 12v battery and take these regulators out of the circuit to check them.